# Accessing multiple Git repos in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022, webview2

I am looking for a way to use Visual Studio 2022 to access and sync with two different repositories. One repository is C# code. The other is Javascript code. Both repositories are currently on Github and are separate.

In one mode, I modify the javascript code using a text editor and XAMPP as a localhost to test the code.

I am trying to use C# and Webview2 inside Visual Studio 2022 to test my javascript code. I would like to add the JS code into my VS2022 project (Using Add existing item and point to files in the JS Code repository) and  have it sync with the JS repo. The C# code would only sync with the C# repo.

I have read that Visual Studio 2022 supports multiple repositories.

I found this on Devblogs.microsoft.com:
[Multi-Repo Branching](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-new-git-features-to-visual-studio-2022/#multi-repo-branching)

In short, I need some of my files to be part of one repository while other files are part of a second repository. Can this be done? If so, what are the steps.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Please, try to split the introduction, and the problem (This is implied in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))   I tried to make a start to make your question more attractive, by simply adding some carriage returns, but ...... (got lost )  Maybe you can make your real question easier to read? 

Comment: There is VS2022 feature to have multiple git repos in the same project, which may fit your needs: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/multi-repo-support-in-visual-studio/

Comment: *"I would like be able to edit the JS code in VS2022 and have it sync with the JS repo"* - so what is exactly preventing you from editing code directly in JS repo?

Comment: Renat, yes that is the page I was referencing. The link did not show up. So, part of my question is will that meet my needs.